# java.lang.NumberFormatException while reading from a file

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to create a basic program, it reads a file of unknown number of numbers arranged in a matrix, creates a list of arrays in String format to read it and then parses that to int for multiple other processes. I'm getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` when parsing, I know its probably because of a blank value getting parsed to an int. I have looked at other questions but can't seem to get it fixed. Here's part of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                
                String[] aLine = line.split("/t");
                br.readLine();
                numLine.add(aLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    for (int i=0; i < numLine.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < numLine.get(i).length; j++){
            System.out.print(numLine.get(i)[j] + " ");
            //  if (!((numLine.get(i)[j]).equals("\t"))){
            intList.add(Integer.parseInt(numLine.get(i)[j]));
            //  }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And here is what the error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6    10  9   10  12  "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at readingTextFiles.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Please take into account I'm a newbie programmer, got all this from research, so I'm not really sure how the theory works.

Comment: At which line you're getting the exception.

Comment: @prudhvi Of course you get it at

__intList.add(Integer.parseInt(numLine.get(i)[j]));__

don't you think?

Comment: Yes, I was lazy to look at first. Let me see the issue.

Comment: i added the error that java prints for you to take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the delimiter as @kayKay mentioned, You are trying to read the line again. I think you shouldn't ??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] aLine = line.split("\t"); // Also as kaykay mentioned change /t to \t
        //br.readLine();  // You are reading the line again - Comment it out 
        numLine.add(aLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e){
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

for (int i=0; i < numLine.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < numLine.get(i).length; j++){
        System.out.print(numLine.get(i)[j] + " ");
        //  if (!((numLine.get(i)[j]).equals("\t"))){
        intList.add(Integer.parseInt(numLine.get(i)[j]));
    }
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: i can't believe i made such stupid mistakes, still thank you for solving it, i wish the uttermost blessings for you

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of the program? The tab character is represented by `\t` and not `/t` (`line.split("\\t");`). Additionally, you will need to add validation checks that each line you read is actually an `Integer`

Comment: didn't notice the /t, i changed it and the error goes away, but it only prints lines 1 and 3 of my 4 line text file

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: Never mind. Check Sunil Rajashekar's answer for the reason why that's happening